# Angularjs : How to get the dimension of pdf doc in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Actually I need to get the width and height of the document and also which type of document that is which means pdf or word or .exe by without using .extension.

programattecially I need to read the file type and file dimension in angularjs.

Anyone please tell the solution & My code as follows:

```
 $scope.demofun = function () {
        var allowedFormats = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png','pdf'];
         var unsupportedSizes=false;
                    if ($scope.file1[0].size < (5 * 1024 * 1024)) {
```

//Here I will check the file size and restrict the file if the size is not satisfy my condition.

//And I need to allow only A4 size pdf when uploading for that I want to get the dimension of pdf document but I don't able to get the dimension of pdf

for that I write the code like this but it will wont works:

```
 if(($scope.file1[0].width >=21 && $scope.file1[0].width <=22) && ($scope.file1.height >=29.7 && $scope.file1.height <=30.7)){
```

How can I read the dimension in angular?